# PHP/MySQL Based Orgchart Algorithm

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

I am attempting to create a collapsible organizational chart using a MySQL database and PHP. I've got a proof of concept, but the algorithm I'm using to generate the relationship tree is very slow. I'm working with a large data set (30K+ entries). The data is modeled as such:

id, Name, Position #, Supervisor Position #

I'm currently generating the 'tree view' like this:

```
//pseudo code
class Person {
    constructor(position number, reports to) {
        //create an array of all of the people who report to me
        $query = "SELECT * FROM data WHERE reports_to = my_position";
        $reports_to = results from query;
    }
}

//Create a new person object
me = new Person(position number, NULL);

unroll(me);

function unroll(me) {
    //for every person that reports me to , unroll them
    foreach($reports_to as $reportee) {
        unroll($reports_to_position_number, $my_position_number); //recursion
    }
    //print name/position/etc
}
```

I believe the issue is in the recursion. This works fine for a couple hundred entries. Once we get an employee with 4000 reportees, however, it takes several minutes to execute. Any suggestions on different approaches, ways to improve the current alogirthm, etc.?

Comment: Don't dump in pseudocode in a PHP question. It can't be much harder to make that actual PHP code.

Comment: I cannot see any recursion in your "code"

Comment: I added the comment to mark the recursion above (the unroll function is calling the unroll function if I have a direct report). Also added a bit more context to the "pseudo code". (DB query, foreach loop)